# RegEx in javascript freezes and never returns a value

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a general pattern to be used in matching domain names with URLs. I have a case like the code below. The problem is that when I run the code, the browser freezes and I close it manually. The variable `domain` holds domain names which can be of the form: `yahoo.com` and also `us.yahoo.com`. The variable `myString` is a URL to be tested against the stored one. The test should be successful if the strings share the stored domain name, e.g. in the example below, the match will be -1 because the domain is `google.co.uk` while the string has: `google.com`. But I'm not getting -1 result. Instead, the program freezes. What could be the problem?

```
var domain="accounts.google.co.uk";
myString="https://accounts.google.com/ManageAccount";

var result=myString.search("(https:\/\/)(.*\.)*"+domain+"(\/.*)*(\/)*");
console.log(result);
```

**EDIT:**
Also tried:

```
var patt = new RegExp("(https:\/\/)(.*\.)*"+domain+"(\/.*)*(\/)*");
var result=patt.test(myString)
```

The same problem. The browser freezes and can't inspect code.

Comment: Use `/regex/.test(str)` instead, and escape that domain

Comment: Are you looking for exact matches? If so, create an `a` element (`document.createElement`), assign your string as the `href` value - and then check if the `hostname` property (or `host` maybe if a port is in play) of that object matches the domain you are looking for.

Comment: [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) and [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782959/js-regex-freezes-my-browsers)

Comment: You can use these tools - instead of crashing your browser: http://regexr.com/ - https://regex101.com/  - I know there are some really good ones somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating a RegExp from a string you need to escape the backslashes:

```
myString.search("(https:\\/\\/)(.*\\.)*"+domain+"(\\/.*)*(\\/)*")
```

I honestly don't know why it freezes instead of throwing an error or just failing to match properly.

Comment: Also, the dots in "domain" should be escaped if you want to literally match a dot instead of any character.
var domain="accounts\\.google\\.co\\.uk";

Comment: @Bartez This is so important! Very often, I see firewall rules, that allow access to `account.paypal.com` (or the like) - guess why Spam-Mails are using domains like `accountXpaypal.com`? 'Cause dot matches all :-)

Comment: @Bartez Great point! Probably the most common mistake when dealing with regexp. It's so easy to overlook since an unescaped dot matches a dot just fine and you think everything is as it should be.

Comment: @Bartez Thanks. Yes, I want to match exact dot `.` as it is in the domain. But, these URLs are read from a file and entered like this. I do not want to change their format in the file. How can I replace `.` with `\\.` on-the-fly? Is it `\` or `\\`. I understand the double `\\` whith the `/` but why double `\\` with the dot?